# Insert a line before a certain line in a file

Tags: text-processing

I found how to insert a line after a certain line in bash

```
sed -i '/oh-my-zsh.sh/aplugins=(git symfony2)' ~/.zshrc
```

Result:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
plugins=(git symfony2)
```

But I would like to insert my line before `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'a' in '...sh/aplug..." is for 'add' and puts the new text after the search pattern. Replace it with 'i' for 'insert' to put the text before the search pattern. Like this:

```
sed -i '/oh-my-zsh.sh/iplugins=(git symfony2)' ~/.zshrc'
```

This answer and MUCH more can be found at: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).